# What if a question marked as duplicate has a better answer then the orignal?

Tags: discussion

Login problems after update to Magento 1.8 [are](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/onepage-checkout-already-registered-customer-login-redirects-to-create-an-accou) a [common](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55477/login-problems-after-update-to-magento-1-9/55502) [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=form+key+login)

However, the best answer and the only one that shows the right that to solve it that I found, is in a question marked as duplicate:

[Customer Cannot Login After an Update to EE 1.13.1.0 (or CE 1.8.1.0)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18464/customer-cannot-login-after-an-update-to-ee-1-13-1-0-or-ce-1-8-1-0/18489#18489)

I voted to close a new question as duplicate of *this one* and not the original one. However, people who find it will probably follow the link to the first one with less-quality answers.

How to handle this? Is it possible to reopen the question and close the "original"? Or should the answer copied to the original?

Answer (score 4):

IMO you should vote to reopen the question with the better answer and when that gets reopened vote to close the one with the "lower quality" answers.

Answer (score 0):

What I remember there is a way to merge questions for such cases, but dont remember the exact circumstances for this.
But as you can choose which gets marked as duplicated from what, i usually decide which has the more precise question.